# yaml-cpp modifies underlying container even for const nodes?

Tags: c++, c++17, yaml-cpp

I have a test.yml file,

```
test1:
  test1_file: 'test.yml'
```

I want to load this yaml file in C++ code and retrieve data from it.

For my use case, there are additional files which must be *merged* into the data. I found an answer to that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41337824/1111557) (I think...). So, [yaml-cpp](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp) which seems nifty. Frankly, its interface seemed a little weird, but I really didn't want to go reinvent the wheel. That `const YAML::Node & cnode(const YAML::Node & node) { return node;}` is *quite* a code smell.

Okay, so I've got some code which tries to navigate to a given node...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>

using node_name = std::string;
using node_path = std::vector<node_name>;

const YAML::Node & constify(const YAML::Node & node) {
    return node;
}

YAML::Node navigate(const YAML::Node & root_node, const node_path & path) {

    // no path elements?
    if ( path.empty() ) {
        return root_node;
    }

    // any elements are empty?
    if ( std::any_of(path.begin(), path.end(), [](const auto & part){return part.empty();}) ) {
        throw std::invalid_argument{"navigate to node_path with empty elements"};
    }

    // set up initial root node info
    YAML::Node current = root_node;
    const node_name * parent_node_name = nullptr;

    auto throw_path_not_found = [&](const node_name & element_name) {
        node_path not_found_node_path;
        if ( parent_node_name ) {
            // parent_node_name points to the last processed parent
            // if we pass it as-is as an end-iterator, then it will
            // not be included in the container. So increment it.
            //
            // Then, we're at the current node name (which wasn't found)
            // so increment it once more to have the full path.
            parent_node_name += 2;

            not_found_node_path = {&*path.begin(), parent_node_name};
        } else {
            not_found_node_path = {path.begin(), path.begin() + 1};
        }

        // throw yaml_path_not_found{not_found_node_path, current, element_name};
        std::string err_msg{"path not found: "};
        std::for_each(not_found_node_path.begin(), not_found_node_path.end(), [&](const node_name & n){err_msg += n + ".";});
        throw std::runtime_error{std::move(err_msg)};
    };

    // query node to see if we can continue
    auto query_node_type = [&](const node_name & element_name){
        switch (current.Type()) {
        case YAML::NodeType::Scalar:
            // Reached end of node chain before reaching end of desired node path?
            if ( &element_name != &path.back() ) {
                throw_path_not_found(element_name);
            }
            return;
        case YAML::NodeType::Sequence: // aka array
            // this can be fine if the next node element is an integer to access the array
            // otherwise we'll get an Undefined node on the next iteration.
            return;
        case YAML::NodeType::Map:
            // this can be fine if the next node element is a key into the map
            // otherwise we'll get an Undefined node on the next iteration.
            return;
        case YAML::NodeType::Null:
            // the node path exists but contains no value ???
            // more like a std::set, I think?
            // if this causes issues, then fix it.
            return;
        case YAML::NodeType::Undefined:
            throw_path_not_found(element_name);

        // no-default:
        // allow compiler to warn on changes to enum
        }

        throw std::logic_error{std::string{"unexpected node type "} + std::to_string(current.Type()) + " returned from yaml-cpp"};
    };

    // loop through path elements querying to see if we've prematurely stopped
    for ( const auto & element : path ) {
        current = current[element];
        query_node_type(element);
        parent_node_name = &element;
    }

    return current;
}

node_path split_node_path(const std::string & path) {
    node_path result;

    result.emplace_back();

    // prod code just uses boost::algorithm::string::split
    for ( char c : path ) {
        if ( '.' == c ) {
            result.emplace_back();
            continue;
        }
        result.back().push_back(c);
    }

    return result;
}
```

The idea is that I should be able to provide a *node path*, eg `"test1.test1_file"` and it should retrieve the node for that. But, what I've noticed is that doing so works great for the first time, but the second time ends up throwing because the node wasn't found. Wait, what?

Yeah, okay:

```
void dump(const YAML::Node & node) {
    std::cout << "...DUMP...\n" << YAML::Dump(node) << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if ( 3 != argc ) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: ./a.out test.yml test1.test1.file\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    try {
        YAML::Node root_node = YAML::LoadFile(argv[1]);

        dump(root_node);

        navigate(root_node, split_node_path(argv[2]));

        dump(root_node);

        navigate(root_node, split_node_path(argv[2]));

    } catch (const std::exception & e) {
        std::cerr << "exception: " << e.what() << '\n';
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Building that and executing it `g++ test.cpp -lyaml-cpp -std=c++17` with `g++ (Ubuntu 6.2.0-3ubuntu11~16.04) 6.2.0 20160901` succeeds. Calling it gives unexpected output, however:

`$ ./a.out test.yml test1.test1_file
...DUMP...
test1:
  test1_file: test.yml
...DUMP...
test1_file: test.yml
exception: path not found: test1.`

I fully expect the dumps to be identical (and no exception to be thrown): `navigate()` accepts a `const YAML::Node &`. That tells me that it *should not modify the root node*. So exactly where is it being modified? More importantly, what am I doing wrong?

I suspect it's related to the other answer needing that `cnode()` function to const-ify `YAML::Node`s. But when I've tried to do the same, it doesn't seem to help (as evidenced by the `constify()` function which isn't used in this minimal example).

Answer (score 3):

`YAML::Node` is a reference type, not a value type. This means that `const YAML::Node&` is a bit misleading; it's like saying `const unique_ptr<T>&`. You can modify the underlying value `T`.

Moreover, there's a bit of a the YAML API that's a little confusing in loops like this.

```
YAML::Node current = ...;
for ( const auto & element : path ) {
    // this actually is a mutating call; it identifies the root node
    // with the sub-node
    current = current[element];
}
```

Comment: So how do you traverse without using recursion or destroying the tree?

Comment: You have to use recursion.

Comment: .. or add a layer of indirection, e.g., unique_ptr with an empty deleter.